# "Literal does not match format" error when calling a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

A function throws an error `literal does not match format as string` when I am trying to execute it.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_payroll_earn (p_person_id    IN NUMBER,
                                            p_pay_period   IN DATE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   earnings   NUMBER (7, 2);
BEGIN
     SELECT SUM (
               DECODE (pec.classification_name,
                       'Earnings', TO_NUMBER (prrv.result_value),
                       0))
               earnings
       INTO earnings
       FROM per_all_people_f papf,
            per_all_assignments_f paaf,
            pay_assignment_actions paa,
            pay_payroll_actions ppa,
            hr_all_organization_units_tl halu,
            per_all_positions pap,
            per_time_periods ptp,
            pay_run_results prr,
            pay_run_result_values prrv,
            pay_input_values_f pivf,
            pay_personal_payment_methods_f pppmf,
            pay_element_classifications pec,
            pay_element_types_f petf
      WHERE     SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date
                            AND papf.effective_end_date
            AND ppa.effective_date BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date
                                       AND paaf.effective_end_date
            AND papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
            AND paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'
            AND paaf.assignment_id = paa.assignment_id
            AND paa.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id
            AND ppa.action_type IN ('R', 'Q')
            AND paa.action_status = 'C'
            AND ppa.action_type <> 'B'
            AND paaf.organization_id = halu.organization_id
            AND ppa.time_period_id = ptp.time_period_id
            AND paa.assignment_action_id = prr.assignment_action_id
            AND prrv.run_result_id = prr.run_result_id
            AND prrv.input_value_id = pivf.input_value_id
            AND pivf.name = 'Pay Value'
            AND pivf.uom = 'M'
            AND TO_CHAR (ptp.start_date, 'RRRRMM') =
                   NVL (p_pay_period, TO_CHAR (ptp.start_date, 'RRRRMM'))
            AND paaf.assignment_id = pppmf.assignment_id(+)
            AND (       pppmf.assignment_id IS NOT NULL
                    AND ppa.effective_date BETWEEN pppmf.effective_start_date
                                               AND pppmf.effective_end_date
                 OR pppmf.assignment_id IS NULL)
            AND papf.person_id = p_person_id
            AND pec.classification_id = petf.classification_id
            AND petf.element_type_id = prr.element_type_id
            AND SYSDATE BETWEEN petf.effective_start_date
                            AND petf.effective_end_date
   ORDER BY papf.person_id;

   RETURN earnings;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN 'error' || SQLERRM;
END fn_payroll_earn;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the error is on the below line

```
AND TO_CHAR(PTP.START_DATE, 'RRRRMM') = NVL(P_PAY_PERIOD, TO_CHAR(PTP.START_DATE, 'RRRRMM'))
```

P_PAY_PERIOD is a date, and you are doing to_char on PTP.START_DATE.  So oracle is trying to do a comparison between a date (P_PAY_PERIOD) and a string meaning it needs to do an implicit cast and this is failing.

Changing it to the below should resolve the issue

```
AND TO_CHAR(PTP.START_DATE, 'RRRRMM') = NVL(TO_CHAR(P_PAY_PERIOD, 'RRRRMM'),TO_CHAR(PTP.START_DATE, 'RRRRMM'))
```

Added below worked example of the issue and fix.

-- Below replicates the error you are seeing.

```
declare

  v_date date := sysdate;
  v_test varchar2(1) default null;

begin

  select 'X' into v_test from dual where TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'RRRRMM') = NVL    (v_date, TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'RRRRMM'));

end;
```

-- Below fixes the issue

```
declare

  v_date date := sysdate;
  v_test varchar2(1) default null;

begin

  select 'X' into v_test from dual where TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'RRRRMM') = NVL(TO_CHAR(v_date, 'RRRRMM'), TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'RRRRMM'));

end;
```

Comment: @tejaswiboddu That is very strange, I do not see anything else in your code that would cause this.  I have added minimal example to show the error and the fix.